# Bootstrap - row with images, row with text - needs to be aligned on smaller devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with bootstrap formatting when viewed on smaller screens. I've checked out 'similar' answers but can't get a fix for it.
Below is the basic html after a few different experiments with grid elements.
I've attached a photo to show what I am looking for also.
Thanks for your help!
I need the text column below the image column to remain always below it's respective column. Unfortunately I can't post an image.

IMAGE1   IMAGE2    IMAGE3
text1    text2     text3

should go to:

IMAGE1
text1
IMAGE2
text2
IMAGE3
text3

```
    <section class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 element-img"</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 element-img"</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 element-img"</div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">text</div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">text</div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">text</div>                                 
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope that understood your problem:
Why don't you put the texts in the same column as the images they are belonging to?

Example:

```
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="img-element"></div>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="img-element"></div>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="img-element"></div>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>                                 
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That would work I guess, but in this case I think I need them to be in seperate rows/columns. The text is formatted to be inside a 'square' the same size as the image, with padding, some slide-in js scripts, etc. So it's like a separate entity. I hope I'm being clear here. The image and the text occupy boxes of similar sizes with borders, and padding, etc

Comment: So I think you have to style the image and the text elements or a div wrapper instead of the column. I suspect putting these elements in the same column is the only way to achieve the desired order of your elements on mobile devices.